# Truncated harmonic oscillator gives wrong Heisenberg uncertainty?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, hilbert-space, harmonic-oscillator, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

When I calculate the fundamental commutator, $[x,p]$, in finite-dimensional Hilbert space (Heisenberg picture), the result is not proportional to identity, e.g. if I put $n=2$ (operators in natural units):
\begin{equation}
[x,p]=i[a,a^\dagger]=i\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & -2
\end{array}\right)=i(I-(n+1)|n\rangle \langle n|).
\end{equation}
This gives wrong Heisenberg uncertainty for the $n$-th state, $\Delta x\Delta p\geq\frac{1}{2}|\langle n|[x,p]|n\rangle|$.

What went wrong here? Are $x$ and $p$ should be represented in infinite dimension because they are unbounded? On the other hand, solving with series expansion in the Schrödinger picture forces us to trim the series, yields a finite $n$ to give a normalizable solution. How can one solve this discrepancy between these two?

Comment: If it's finite-dimensional then it's not a harmonic oscillator. What you're describing is a *truncated* harmonic oscillator.

Comment: It is a well-known fact that $[x,p]=1$ cannot hold in a finite-dimensional vector space, inasmuch as $\mathrm{tr}[x,p]\equiv 0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a perfectly natural state of affairs:

> the [commutator] is not proportional to identity.

If the operators $A$ and $B$ are trace-class, together with their products $AB$ and $BA$, then the cyclicity of the trace requires that
$$
\mathrm{Tr}(AB)=\mathrm{Tr}(BA),
$$
and therefore that
$$
\mathrm{Tr}([A,B]) = \mathrm{Tr}(AB-BA)=\mathrm{Tr}(AB)-\mathrm{Tr}(BA)=0.
$$
In finite dimensions, all operators are trace-class, which means that no finite-dimensional commutator can have a nonzero trace. This implies that no commutator in finite dimensions can be proportional to the identity.

Now, to be sure, if you're trying to simulate a harmonic oscillator numerically, on a truncated number-state basis, then yes, the fact that the commutator isn't equal to one does pose a problem. (However, because of the above, it's a mistake to ascribe this behaviour to the number-state basis, since *all* discretizations that will fit in a computer will show this behaviour.)

So, how does one solve this? Essentially, by ensuring that any differences between $[x,p]$ and $iI$ occur in subspaces (such as $\mathrm{span}\{|N\rangle\}$ in your case) that do not contain any meaningful dynamics, i.e. by ensuring that
$$
\langle \phi | \left([x,p]-iI\right)|\psi\rangle
$$
is either zero or negligibly small for all states $|\phi\rangle$ and $|\psi\rangle$ that are of interest to the dynamics you're simulating.

There's a good deal of ink that's been spilt over the properties of the truncated harmonic oscillator (enough, say, that I get to [pull a shameless plug](https://arxiv.org/abs/1109.5724) while I'm at this) and its properties are plenty interesting, but it's important to keep in mind just how different from the full harmonic oscillator it's forced to be by the finite dimensionality.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I just realised this thing has a name and some related literature.

Comment: Yeah, this happens to all of us. The trick is learning to do the literature search that will get you to realise those connections exist *before* you spend months working on results that have been known since the seventies.

Answer (score 0):

I answer only the first part of your question, and I think it will be enough:

If you fix the operators you can calculate the commutation rule (you can't impose it, but calculate). On the other hand if you fix the commutation rule you could have imposed a strong constraint on the operators.

If you impose that the operators $a, a^\dagger$ has the same form as in the infinite dimensional case is not still true that is $[x,p] = i \hbar [a,a-^\dagger]$, because the last state $|2\rangle$ is in the kernel of the operator $a^\dagger$, while in the infinite dimensional case is not, instead the operators $x,p$ have they same value as before, so you can't write anymore the ladder operators in terms of position and momentum with the formula that yields the relation between commutators.

So you have fixed the Hilbert space and defines two operators $a,a^\dagger$ with the commutation rule that you've find, but you can't say that this implies that commutation rule for position and momentum, because to find that you have to take the operators used the in the infinite dimensional case, restrict them on your current Hilbert space and calculate the new commutator.